# How to put values from several rows together in one row (separated by comma)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have a dataframe(based on a grouped object) like this:

```
  df:
         col2
   col1 
    a    ab
         cd
         ef
    b    kj
         jk
         l
```

What I want to get is this:

```
df:
   col1   col2
0   a      ab,cd,ef
1   b      kj,jk,l
2
.
.
.
```

So basically I want the strings from one 'group' as one 'string' column value.
Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I think you can do `df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then you `groupby` on `level=0` of your index and `apply` a `lambda` to `join` the values:

```
In [175]:
df.groupby(level=0)['col2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))

Out[175]:
col1
a    ab,cd,ef
b     kj,jk,l
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had something like this that did not work. I think the `groupby` on `level=0` does the trick.

Comment: I think some users don't realise you can call `groupy` on an existing index level, glad I could help